# Not able to deserialize JSON response in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, discord

so I'm currently trying to deserialize an JSON API. 
I'm using the same code that I've been using successfully for other APIs to. 
But every single variable just returns 0.

```
    public class RootObject
{
    public int lat { get; set; }
    public int lon { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_iso { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class UVGetter
{
    public static async Task<RootObject> UVApiProxy(double lat, double lon)
    {
        var Timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

        var http = new HttpClient();
        string WeatherApiKey = "secret";
        var url = String.Format($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi/history?appid=" + WeatherApiKey + "&lat=" + Math.Round(lat) + "&lon=" + Math.Round(lon) + "&start=" + Timestamp + "&end=" + Timestamp);
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var uvdata = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        Agara.Program.WeatherApiCalls++;
        Console.WriteLine(uvdata.lat + "\n" + uvdata.lon + "\n" + uvdata.date_iso.ToString() + "\n" + uvdata.date + "\n" + uvdata.value);
        return uvdata;
    }
}
```

The result looks like this

```
[{"lat":54,"lon":9,"date_iso":"2018-05-08T12:00:00Z","date":1525780800,"value":5.62}]
```

And the variables (uvdata.lat for example) just contain zeros though the API information should be stored in those.

Comment: I recommend using the [Json Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). Easy to use and good error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON does not contain a `RootObject`, it's an *array* of `RootObject`. So:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject[]))
// ...
var uvdata = (RootObject[])serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Alternatively, using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var uvData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(result);
```

You could also deserialize into a `List<RootObject>` instead of an array.

If you want to preserve leading zeroes, deserialize those properties as strings, as integers don't have that concept, so:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_iso { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [] means a list/array so he could use both

Comment: Yeah there are many collection types. When deserializing though you hardly ever should want to modify the collection, so I'd prefer the simplest: an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is an array not single object, so you should deserialize to array. You can also use [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for that (imho it's easy to use), you can easily create your `class` by just copying your json string and inside VisualStudio

> Edit -> PasteSpecial -> Paste JSON As Classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int lat { get; set; }
    public int lon { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_iso { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public float value { get; set; }
}

string json  = @"[{""lat"":54,""lon"":9,""date_iso"":""2018 - 05 - 08T12: 00:00Z"",""date"":1525780800,""value"":5.62}]";
Class1[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);
```

Comment: Well.. I didn't change anything, I'm just saying that its easy to use, and showing an example.

Comment: You did change something, namely the same as I did in my answer and what ultimately is the OP's problem: `RootObject` -> `RootObject[]`.

Comment: @CodeCaster `RootObject` naming is generated by VisualStudio, it's just coincidence and in my example it's `Class1[]` not `RootObject[]`. But anyway, thank you for your note, I've updated my answer and I'm not saying that you can't achieve that with `DataContractJsonSerializer `, I'm just saying that you can **also** use Newtonsoft's json deserializer.

Comment: My point was not the name... it was the array part. Thanks for adding that.